# Deserializing to an object and an array of objects using RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-5, restsharp

I have an API, that either returns an `object1` with Status code `Ok` or an array of `object2` that contains error messages with Status code that is *not* `Ok`.

For eg:

**Case of good response:**

```
{
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "Id": "some_id",
      "SomeDataField": "12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

My `object1` model:

```
public class MyAPIResponse  // Blueprint for object1
{
    public int TotalSize { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public partial class Record
{    
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeDataField { get; set; }
}
```

**Case of bad response:**

```
[
  {
    "message": "Session expired or invalid",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
  },
    {
    "message": "Some other message",
    "errorCode": "SOME_OTHER_ID"
  }
]
```

My `object2` model:

```
public class Errors : List<Error> { }

public class Error  // Blueprint for object2
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to get response now:

```
public async void SendRequestAndReceiveResponse()
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://some.api.base.address.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("some.url", Method.GET);
    var queryBody = "some_query";
    request.AddParameter("q", queryBody , ParameterType.QueryString);
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + "my_access_token");
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<MyAPIResponse>(request); // Note I'm asking it to be deserialized to object1
    // Do other stuffs with this object1 response...
}
```

If "good response" is coming, it's all nice and well as it gets deserialized to `object1`.

But if "bad response" is coming, then as expected I get this error because it sees array of `object2` in the response but I'm telling it to deserialize to `object1`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'
```

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to create a single class (for eg: `MyAPIResponse` from above) that could hold both good and bad responses which would save me from doing the following to deserialize the good and bad responses?

```
// Good response
var goodResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<MyAPIResponse>(request);

// Bad response
var badResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<Errors>(request);
//Or
var badResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<List<Error>>(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ExecuteAsync<T>` or `ExecuteGetAsync<T>` it doesn't throw, and returns you the exception you mentioned, is that right?

You can check `response.IsSuccessful` and if it's false you can deserialize the `response.Content` to the error type manually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It throws the exception when I call `var goodResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<MyAPIResponse>(request);` if it's coming with errors. So how can I check `response.IsSuccessful`?

Comment: `ExecuteAsync` returns an instance of `RestResponse`, there you can find that property. If it throws on that call, I could advise either upgrading to RS 107, or using a different serializer with RS 106 if you have to use RS 106. Also, the serialization throw behaviour is controlled by the `FailOnDeserializationError` property of the request. If it is set to `false`, `Execute` should not throw. I am not so sure about RS 106 behaviour, but v107 handles it correectly.

Comment: Also https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html